# Como utilizar um array de classe como ponteiro?

Tags: c++, stack, heap

Como faço para utilizar um array de classe como ponteiro? Eu tentei de varias e varias formas, porém o C++ não deixava compilar gerando erros.

Um exemplo da classe(É só um exemplo, a classe que eu preciso utilizar é milhares de vezes maior que essa)

```
class Pessoas
{
private:
    std::string Nome;
public:
    std::string getNome() const { return this->Nome; }

    void setNome(std::string Nome) { this->Nome = Nome; }
};

Pessoas pessoas[1000]; // Forma atual que estou utilizando, compila corretamente, porém eu preciso que ela fique allocada no heap
Pessoas* pessoas = new Pessoas[1000]; // Compila corretamente, porém, eu tenho que utilizar o operador . para acessar os membros, o que me parece estranho pois geralmente eu utilizo o operador ->, dessa forma ela está sendo allocada no heap?
```

Da segunda forma ela está sendo allocada no heap? Se não está como eu faço para allocar no heap?

Um exemplo de como eu queria deixar(Sem fazer a sobrecarga de operadores, como se fosse um ponteiro):

```
pessoas[1]->setNome("Fulano");
pessoas[2]->setNome("Sicrano");
```

Estou tentando armazenar a classe no heap pois como a classe é grande acredito que não vai caber no stack, outro motivo também é que preciso que os dados da classe fique até o final de funções extremamentes grandes o que eu acredito que não acontece no stack.

Comment: Pela sintaxe que tem de exemplo parece-me que está a procura de um array de ponteiros, que seria `Pessoa **pessoas`. No entanto isso implica alocar cada ponteiro de pessoa manualmente. Caso contrário pode utilizar como tem e usar a sintaxe com `.`, no final é a diferença entre ter um array de pessoas e um array de ponteiros para pessoas

Comment: Como assim alocar cada ponteiro manualmente? Para cada pessoa eu teria que allocar?

Comment: Algo como `pessoas[0] = new Pessoas();`, que naturalmente aplicado com um `for`. Quando eu disse ponteiro referia-me a objeto, alocar cada Pessoa do array manualmente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No primeiro caso está na pilha e no segundo na heap. Mas em ambos os casos os membros deveriam ser acessados com o `.` e não com `->`.

Só se usa `->` para derreferenciar um ponteiro. Mas você já fez isso ao chamar o índice com o operador `[]`. Então o que sobrou foi uma instância de `Pessoas` cujos membros vc acessa com `.`

Ex:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Pessoas
{
    private:
        std::string Nome;

    public:
        std::string getNome() const { return this->Nome; }
        void setNome(std::string Nome) { this->Nome = Nome; }
};


int main()
{
    Pessoas pArray[1000];
    Pessoas* pessoas = new Pessoas[1000];

    pArray[0].setNome("Pessoa Array");
    pessoas[0].setNome("Pessoa Heap");

    cout << "!" << pArray[0].getNome() << endl;
    cout << "!" << pessoas[0].getNome() << endl;
}
```

Compilei com visual C++ 2015

A saída ficou:

```
!Pessoa Array
!Pessoa Heap
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas por que nesse caso não se aplica o operador -> já que está no heap e é um ponteiro?

Comment: Editei a resposta. Ve se ficou claro.

Comment: Ficou sim, obrigado.